# Unable to link store operations with a custom proxy

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to implement Indexeddb proxy defined in ExtJs for sencha. What is the way in which I need to register the proxy listeners so that the store operations can be mapped to the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

See the below, it is indexeddb example from Sencha.

http://www.grgur.com/indexeddb/sample/bdb-cell-editing.js